# Adjoining a separable element to a field makes the extension separable

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $k$ be a field, and $K$ be an extension. Suppose $a\in K$ is separable over $k$. What's a clever way to show that $k(a)$ is separable (i.e., that all elements of $k(a)$ have separable minimal polynomials)?

Comment: it's obvious that $a$ and all elements lying in $k$ are separable, but what about multiples or powers of $a$, which also lie in $k(a)$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the characterization of separability in terms of counting the number of embeddings in an algebraic closure?

Comment: Yes, I figured it out using that trick. Thank you @EricWofsey!